# How do I convert the firestore data to a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have these codes:

```
const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState();

  const getData = async () => {
    const citiesRef = firestore.collection("users");
    const snapshot = await citiesRef
      .where("item.itemName", "==", true)
      .where("item", "==", false)
      .get();
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log("No matching documents.");
      return;
    }

    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.data());
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  });

  return <div>Month</div>;
};

export default App;
```

If I'll `console.log(doc.data())` this is what is shows:
[image]

How can I convert this into a JSON object?

I wanted to have a JSON object in order to filter the data. Thank you.

Comment: That indeed seems to be a JSON object. Are you trying to get an array like a list of users?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Something like that since I wanted to filter all those data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get an *array* of objects containing all documents' data to filter them, try this:

```
const usersData = snapshot.docs.map(d => ({id: d.id, ...d.data()}))
// set this array in your state
setUsers(usersData)
```

This will be an array and you can use methods like `filter()`, `find()` as required. For example, to get users having `admin` role in their `roles` array:

```
const admins = usersData.filter(user => user.roles.includes("admin"))
```

Comment: Thank you. It does work. But how can I put those data in `setUsers`. I tried this `snapshot.docs.map((d) => setUsers({ id: d.id, ...d.data() }));` and it did not work.

Comment: @RavenousRed `setUsers(usersData)`. Also change initial state to `useState([]);` with empty array.

Comment: Is there something wrong with my codes I posted? When I `console.log(users)`, it would render an repeatedly show the `users` data

Comment: @RavenousRed that seems to be react related thing. I've seen the `useEffect(() => {}, [])` to have an empty array that way.